# Phonegap build for different versions of android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to build my phonegap project for specific versions for android, like android 4.4 ( Kitkat ), 5.0 (Lollipop) and lower versions too.

```
phonegap build
```

On running build command, it builds for the api level of sdk currently being used.

What command should I run or what settings should I make so as to get version specific builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your phonegap project folder, navigate to `platforms/android/`. Open the `project.properties` for editing.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools. 
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED! 
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure. 
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.

target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

Change the `target = android-16` for android version 4.1, `target = android-19` for android 4.4, `target = android-21` for android 5.0.
Now when you build you will get android version specific builds.

[Note : You need to have the respective api installed. You can open android adk manager by running `android`, and download the packages.]

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Though installing packages was a bit time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

You should edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

`minSdkVersion` is the minimum API Level required for the application to run.

`maxSdkVersion` is the maximum API Level on which the application is designed to run.

`targetSdkVersion` is the API Level that the application targets.

The accepted answer proposes the use of project.properties target, but that is for specifying the SDK used to compile the app, but you shouldn't do that, you should always use the latest installed and change the values on the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks, this also works fine. I had previously tried this but I was setting only `android:minSdkVersion`